# SelectedItem doesn't update properly when trying to share items between views

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a scenario where the same collection of items can be viewed in different ways.  That is, we have multiple visual representations for the same data.  In order to keep our application visually clean you can only view one of these views at a time.  The problem I'm having is that if you change the selected item while viewing View #1 then when you switch to View #2 the selected item isn't updating properly.

My steps for reproducing:

- On View #1 select Item #1.
- Toggle to View #2 - at this point Item #1 is selected
- Scroll down to "Item #200" and select it
- Toggle back to View #1
- Item #1 will still be highlighted and if you scroll down to Item #200 it is also highlighted

It seems like when the listbox is collapsed the selection changes aren't being picked up.  What am I missing? Is it expected that the PropertyChanged events won't update the UI elements if they aren't visible?

I have a very simplified version of my code below. Basically, I have a shared array that is being bound to two different ListBox controls.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="SharedListBindingExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SharedListBindingExample"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding List1}">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SharedListItem}">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Background="Red" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>


    </ListBox>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="listBox2" ItemsSource="{Binding List2}" Background="AliceBlue" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </Style>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SharedListItem}">
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>

    </ListBox>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click">Toggle View</Button>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace SharedListBindingExample
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            listBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            listBox2.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            listBox2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            listBox1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SharedListBindingExample
{
  public class TwoPropertiesForSameListViewModel
  {
    private readonly List<SharedListItem> _sharedList;

    public TwoPropertiesForSameListViewModel()
    {
        _sharedList = new List<SharedListItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
        {
            _sharedList.Add(new SharedListItem($"Item #{i}"));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SharedListItem> List1
    {
        get
        {
            return _sharedList;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<SharedListItem> List2
    {
        get
        {
            return _sharedList;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**SharedListItem:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SharedListBindingExample
{
  public class SharedListItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private bool _isSelected;

    public SharedListItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isSelected;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != _isSelected)
            {
                _isSelected = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to use a `CollectionViewSource` object between the two different views to keep the selected item in sync.  I do something similar in my own application.

I have one control which defines a `CollectionViewSource` resource in the Xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="DataView" />
</UserControlResources>
```

The control also has a `DependencyProperty` for the `CollectionViewSource` that allows it to be Data Bound to other controls:

```
public static readonly DataViewProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register( "DataView", typeof( CollectionViewSource ), typeof( YourControlType ),  new PropertyMetadata( null ) );

public CollectionViewSource DataView {
    get { return (CollectionViewSource) GetProperty( DataViewProperty); }
    set { SetProperty( DataViewProperty, value );
}
```

Then in the components constructor, after calling `InitializeComponent`, you have to execute code like this:

```
public MyUserControl() {
    InitializeComponent();

    DataView = FindResource( "DataView" ) as CollectionViewSource;
    DataView.Source = YourObservableCollection;
}
```

In the other view(s) where you want to share this object, you create a new `CollectionViewSource DependencyProperty`.  This allows you to bind the two proeprties to each other in the window that has the different views of your data.  In my second control, I have another `ObservableCollection` object property, but it is not initialized in the control's constructor.  What I do is in the control's `Loaded` event handler, I set that `ObservableCollection` property's value to the value of the `CollectionViewSource` object's Source property.  That is:

```
if ( DataCollection == null && DataView != null ) {
    DataCollection = (ObservableCollection<DataType>) DataView.Source;
    DataGrid.ItemsSource = DataView.View;
}
```

After this, both controls share the same `ObservableCollection` and the same `CollectionViewSource`.  It's the `CollectionViewSource` that keeps the two control's selected item in sync.

Obviously, you can share that `CollectionViewSource` object across as many views as you like.  One control has to declare the object, the others have to share it.

Comment: Yep, ICollectionView and friends did it.  Thanks for pointing me in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

When using WPF, it is recommended to ditch `IEnumerable`s for `ObservableCollection` or `ICollectionView`. You can find more details about these collections on MSDN, but my suggestion is to bind `SelectedItem` of one ListBox to another in XAML (by `SelectedItem = {Binding ElementName='yourList', Path='SelectedItem'}`), so that when one changes, the other one will respond (you should do this for both lists). I have never tried this cyclic binding myself, but I think it will work fine in your case.

Comment: In my application I use ObservableCollections, I just didn't bother in my example project since I'm not updating anything.  I've also been trying to avoid having my views know about each other - in my application these listboxes are on separate controls that know nothing about each other.

Comment: Then try to put a field SharedListSelectedItem in VM and bind both lists to that item --- that should help because you abstracted away what item was selected and still both lists do not know about each other.

Comment: Seems to me that the binding is ok. It seems that ListBox has virtualization enabled and graphic doesn't update accordingly, but if you scroll down and then up again the "fake" selection is gone. With Virtualization disabled seems to work.

Comment: Then I am of no help :) it is a little bit unreasonable to me that graphic will not update in case of INotifyPropertyChange fired when SharedListSelectedIndex changes, but who knows.